# Unit test case :XCTestCase vs Sentestcase

Tags: xctest, sentestingkit

I am writing test case for my application . Just wondering which one to choose between XctestCase and SentestCase ?

Any input will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Apple deprecated OCUnit (SenTestingKit) as of Xcode 5.1, which was released in March 2014.